# Generating list with constraints

Tags: python, list

I need to generate a list of length n that:

1. has elements from the domain [-1, 0, 1]
2. Has exactly k nonzero elements

I understand that my elements will be a subset of the cross-product of [-1, 0, 1] with itself numerous times however simply generating the cross-product using the iterables package and then removing the "wrong" ones isn't possible in a timely manner for n bigger than 10 really.

I'm wondering if there is a feasible way?

N.B. For context the problem is generating Circular Weighing Matrices using search algorithms. Any insight into the problem conceptually is also appreciated.

Comment: Does the list have _at least_ k nonzero elements, or _exactly_ k nonzero elements?

Comment: Oops! Fixed that mistype in the description! And it's exactly k nonzero.

Comment: Do you want to randomly generate a single list that fits your constraints, or do you want to generate all possible lists? And when you say, "from the domain [-1, 0, 1]", does that mean, "any real number between -1 and 1", or just the integers -1, 0, 1?

Comment: It also isn't clear if the resulting list should be pseudo-randomly shuffled and/or if it should contain equal numbers of `-1` and `1`...

Comment: I'm interested in creating _all_ the possible lists. Or, that at least was the suggestion I was provided. I suppose I'm interested in the applicability of it. There need not be an equal number of 1 and -1. And the elements of the list must be -1, 0, 1. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: generate an ordered list containing the number of -1s, 0s, and 1s you require, and iterate through all permutations of that ordering. Like so:

```
import itertools

def generateLists(n, k):
    numberOfZeroes = n - k
    for numberOfOnes in range(0, k+1):
        numberOfNegativeOnes = k - numberOfOnes
        orderedList = [-1] * numberOfNegativeOnes + [0] * numberOfZeroes + [1] * numberOfOnes
        for possibleOrderings in itertools.permutations(orderedList):
            yield possibleOrderings

for i in generateLists(3, 2):
    print i
```

Output:

```
(-1, -1, 0)
(-1, 0, -1)
(-1, -1, 0)
(-1, 0, -1)
(0, -1, -1)
(0, -1, -1)
(-1, 0, 1)
(-1, 1, 0)
(0, -1, 1)
(0, 1, -1)
(1, -1, 0)
(1, 0, -1)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Note that this generates duplicates.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually incredibly helpful and scalable within my needs. There are additional constraints that I didn't mention before as they didn't apply to the simplification of the problem I had presented but this lends itself to working with them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem reduces to finding lists with `n-k` zeroes and `k` non-zeroes, then specializing the non-zeroes to -1 and 1.

You can do this easily with combinations of indices:

```
def gen_lists(n, k):
    for nzinds in itertools.combinations(range(n), n-k):
        l = [0] * n
        for nz in itertools.product([-1,1], repeat=n-k):
            for i,v in zip(nzinds, nz):
                l[i] = v
            yield l
```

Sample output:

```
>>> for l in gen_lists(3, 1):
...     print l
... 
[-1, -1, 0]
[-1, 1, 0]
[1, -1, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[-1, 0, -1]
[-1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, -1]
[1, 0, 1]
[0, -1, -1]
[0, -1, 1]
[0, 1, -1]
[0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Yes...what makes you think it wouldn't? I'm on Python 2.7, if it matters.

Comment: Because I can't reproduce it, and just looking at it, I think your `l = [0] * n` line should be one loop deeper.

Comment: @DSM: it works for me, seriously. It does return the same list repeatedly, though, so `list(gen_lists(3,1))` produces different output.

Comment: @nneoneo: ah, that's it!  Wow, subtle-- I'm not sure I've come across that before!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to make a big list and remove things you can try to build it up from the bottom. Make k non-zero elements. Make n-k 0 elements. Put them together and then shuffle the mixture:

```
import random
k = 5
n = 10
non_zero = k * [1,-1]
random.shuffle(non_zero)
z = (n-k)*[0]
result = non_zero[0:k] + z
random.shuffle(result) # [0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0]
```